# PHP connection to database after ssh2_connect

Tags: php, postgresql, ssh, remote-access

I have a web site and I am trying to communicate with a PostgreSQL database which is sitting on my personal server (CentOS 7).

I have taken the following steps

- forwarded the ssh port on my server (after disabling password authentication)
- generated the ssh keys and placed them onto the web server
- setup the SSH2.so library on the webserver
- created the php script to establish the connection

These all work fine and my script is capable of making the connection to the ssh server

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$connection = ssh2_connect('xxx.xx.xx.xx', 22);

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'usname',
                      './ssh_key.pub',
                      './ssh_key', 'psword')) {

    echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n";

} else {

    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');

}

?>
```

So all this works but I am struggling to connect to the database on the server I've made the connection to, is there a different way of connecting to the database that works with an ssh connection?

Comment: Why are you trying to go via ssh? Can you not set up PostgreSQL to allow access to your IP via its standard port?

Comment: Apparently not, I tried to open the postgresql port to the web but with no success, I posted a question about that on here and everyone was recommending I do it through ssh

Comment: Can you link to the question?

Comment: you just have a standard ssh "shell" connection. you need to do port forwarding instead.

Comment: As @MarcB says, you could actually set up a persistent tunnel to the box, which wouldn't involve using PHP, then using the standard db access functionality to connect "locally".

Comment: @JonStirling http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239428/postgresql-accessible-to-web-application

Comment: Why are you using SSH to connect to postgres? Just use PHP driver for postgres (http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) and then enable TLS if you want to secure the channel.

Comment: You'd be so much better off using autossh tunnel to create a persistent tunnel. Using any SSH library, be it libssh2 or whatever, will re-negotiate the connection every time. So instead of doing key exchange once it's done every time someone makes an HTTP request, which is just gonna slow things down.

Comment: @neubert will I be able to create an ssh_tunnel using my current method? Unfortunately the server only allows key authentication because it is open to the web

Comment: You can with http://php.net/ssh2-tunnel but you can do key auth with autossh as well.